# Clone by using org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.clone

Tags: java, spring

Is there any disadvantage using org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.clone in spring web service ?

Comment: What are you really trying to ask? disadvantage sounds very vague

Answer (score 6):

From [the Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html):

> This is many times slower than writing clone methods by hand on all
>   objects in your object graph. However, for complex object graphs, or
>   for those that don't support deep cloning this can be a simple
>   alternative implementation

So you have to determine if the simplicity of using a library here is outweighed by the performance issues. Consequently I would measure the performance if this is of concern to you.

You may choose to implement serialisation using this library just to make progress, and replace the serialisation with a hand-rolled solution later. However I'd warn against premature optimisation. Given that you've got a web service, you'll likely be more impacted by network latencies, marshalling/unmarshalling etc.

Comment: Thanks Brian, As you say it will impact my e2e work flow. So could you suggest me / give a simple example how we can have a hand-rolled which will be hand on the objects.

Comment: @greedybuddhaI read this highlight statement in other discussion that SerializationUtils.clone will be slower. Though its solv my purpose but I need some better way to archive this.